# Input data not assign to sql query

Tags: c++, oracle-pro-c

The sql update below will not work but it will update if I comment out  "cin name" at employee update. I don't understand because I already asked for employee name during employee search so the name variable should assigned with data but that's not happening. Somebody help me please? Thank you.

```
            EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
                //int customer_id,cu_id;
                char salary[10],address[50];
                char name[50];
            EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

            fnConnectDB();

            cout<<"Customer Id\t\t: ";
            cin.getline(name,50); // search employee


                EXEC SQL SELECT * INTO :salary,:address,:name FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE NAME = :name;  
            // output empoyee information
            cout<<"\nCustomer Name\t\t: "<<name;
            cout<<"\nCustomer contact\t: "<<salary;
            cout<<"\nCustomer status\t\t: "<<address;
            cout<<"\n\nEnter new value for customer:\n\n";

    // update employee
        //  cout<<"Customer name\t\t: "; // if I comment out this it will update
        //  cin.getline(name,50);   // if I comment out this it will update
            cout<<"Customer salary\t\t: ";
            cin.getline(salary,10);
            cout<<"Customer address\t\t: ";
            cin.getline(address,50);

// check employee name if it initialize
    cout<<"\nCustomer Name\t\t: "<<name;

            EXEC SQL UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY=:salary, ADDRESS=:address WHERE NAME = :name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `NAME = :name` with `NAME = 'name'`

Instead of using colon as **:name** in where condition, **put name under single quotes** just like we do in SQL query statement.

Check this link: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0005909.htm